# How to mute android soft keyboard programmatically?

Tags: android

How to mute android soft keyboard programmatically?
I try to use

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.setStreamMute(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK, true);
```

But this doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the normal volume.  I don't think any keyboard uses the default key click noise, when I was making the keyboard every OEM wanted us to use their own custom ogg files they sent us.  But we did honor normal volume.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isSetSound) {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK);
    } else {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK, false);
    }
```